# How to maintain same session Id for same client for particular session only?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

We used session Id as 
const sessionId=uuid.v4();

But it resulted in giving different session ids for the questions for the same user.
How to maintain the same session Id throughout the session for a user in node.js?

Comment: @Prisoner  Please help me out...

Comment: what u want to do and y u want to store session id, dialogflow maintain session with node js cloud function. ur using cloud function?